# What do the Items on the properties tab of MSVC++ mean?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, class, sealed

I was playing around with my MSVC++ compiler, and the properties tab for my point class said:

```
IsAbstract  - false
IsInjected  - false
IsManaged   - false
IsSealed    - false
IsTemplate  - false
IsValue     - false
```

What do these mean, and why were all of them greyed out except IsAbstract and IsSealed?

Comment: IsAbstract means that a class is abstract, and cannot be instantiated. It requires you to make a class that implements the same methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sealed class is one that you cannot inherit. I assume IsSealed - false means that you can inherit from it.